# error (dcc:1086):redeclaration of uint16_t

Tags: c, mingw

**There is a header file in my project that contains this line:**

```
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
```

**and in MinGW compiler , there is a file "stdint.h" that also has the same line:**

```
typedef unsigned short  uint16_t;
```

**When I compile, I get the following error:**

error (dcc:1086):redeclaration of uint16_t

Can anyone please explain this to me .... I mean they are both unsigned short ..

Comment: "There is a header file in my project that contains the line ..." Why? It is the environment's job to define `uint16_t`, not your project's...

Comment: It is defined in the project in case of using compilers that don't have "stdint.h" file

Comment: Then you should make the including of this file depend on the compiler...

Comment: yes, this is the approach I took :)
Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uint16_t` is already defined in `stdint.h` as an unsigned 16 bit integer type. You should just omit your typedef.

Comment: @glglgl I though that was obvious.